# Boost iterator_facade implementation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iterators

I am hoping someone familiar with the boost iterator_facade implementation can shed some light on why the following meta function is used when selecting either `writable_postfix_increment_proxy` or `postfix_increment_proxy`.

```
template <class Reference, class Value>
struct is_non_proxy_reference
  : is_convertible<
        typename remove_reference<Reference>::type
        const volatile*
      , Value const volatile*
    >
{};
```

This can be found [here](https://github.com/boostorg/iterator/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp#L308) and is used in the metafunction [postfix_increment_result](https://github.com/boostorg/iterator/blob/boost-1.63.0/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp#L284) that selects whether the postfix operator should return either a proxy or the just the iterator. The rest of the `postfix_increment_result` seems pretty clear. Something like..

*if iter::reference is readable and the category is basically the equivalent of input_iterator_tag or output_iterator_tag then a proxy is returned.*

However I am confused about `is_non_proxy_reference`, which appears to be `true` in the case that `Reference` is the same as `Value` ignoring cv qualifiers. In which case `postfix_increment_proxy<Iterator>` else `writable_postfix_increment_proxy<Iterator>` in used.

When is `Reference` going to be a different 'base type' to `Value`? Is this to support returning your own proxy type if you wanted? Or something else?